# How do I free up space on my iPhone when I am no longer storing photos on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have tried to free up space on my iPhone by no longer storing photos on the phone; and yet when there are no photos on the iPhone, iOS still allocated 17.43 GB to it. How do I free up this space so it only takes up no more than 1GB?

In addition, I have disabled the facility to back up to iCloud, as I found it started to download the images from iCloud on it--which is exactly what I do not want!

I want to keep the memory allocated to photos to be as small as possible [~1 GB], and manually copy the image files from my iPhone to my Mac, and then delete the images from my iPhone. Yet for some reason when I have deleted all images from the iPhone, including removing all images in my Recently Deleted folder, it is still reporting that 17.43 GB of space is used by Photos?

What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Settings > Apple ID  > iCloud (left column), is the checkbox next to "Photos" checked or not checked?

Comment: It is unchecked, as I have found that by checking it, it starts copying down the photos from iCloud into my iPhone--something that I do not want, because when I connect my phone to my Mac, I can copy the photos I want to my Mac, and manually delete them and then Remove them from my  iPhone....

Comment: Yes, I agree that's the correct setting. I'm sorry I don't have any other suggestions beyond the standard restart/hard restart/restore from backup/set up as new progression.